# Custom view does not show results in Django Haystack with Elastic Search

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-views, django-haystack

I'm starting using Django Haystack with Elasticsearch.

All right until I started make a Custom View following the simple example in [readthedocs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/views_and_forms.html#new-django-class-based-views).

**search_indexes.py:**

```
class ExperimentIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    owner = indexes.CharField(model_attr='owner')

    def get_model(self):
        return Experiment

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().lastversion_objects.all()
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^search/?$', NepSearchView.as_view(), name='search_view')
```

**urls.py before (without Custom View):**

```
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'))
```

**views.py**

```
class NepSearchView(SearchView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(NepSearchView, self).get_queryset()
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated and \
                self.request.user.groups.filter(name='trustees').exists():
            return queryset  # (with some filter)
        else:
            return queryset
```

**search.html:**

```
{# ... #}
{% for result in page.object_list %}
{% if result.model_name == 'experiment' %}
{% include 'search/experiments.html' %}
{% endif %}
{% if result.model_name == 'study' %}
{% include 'search/studies.html' %}
{% endif %}
{% if result.model_name == 'group' %}
{% include 'search/groups.html' %}
{% endif %}
{% if result.model_name == 'experimentalprotocol' %}
{% include 'search/experimental_protocol.html' %}
{% endif %}
{# ... #}
```

Well, the fact is when using default Haystack `SearchView` I've got the correct matches, while when introducing `NepSearchView`, `page.object_list` is empty and I get `No results found.` in template.

I already ran `manage.py rebuild_index`, searched extensively in web but couldn't find nothing that explains what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the page.object_list variable name for the queryset does not exist.
Try the *object_list* without the 'page' prefix.

instead of

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}
```

use

```
{% for result in object_list %}
```

Alternatively you can provide a custom variable name in the view by appending something like this

```
context_object_name = 'haystack_objects'
```

and use it in the template

```
{% for result in haystack_objects %}
```

Comment: Late, but I thought I'd ask: how'd you go about diagnosing this issue? I struggled for a couple of hours, matching the tutotial in the docs precisely, though was still using the default template with `page.object_list`. Would love to know how to avoid similar headaches in the future.